Как создать словарь от начала до середины списка?
Есть список случайных чисел в диапазоне. На базе этого списка нужно создать словарь, где первая половина списка будет ключами, а вторая их значениями.
Начало кода такое
n = int(input("Введите целое число:"))

list_numbers = list()

for num in range(n):
    list_numbers.append(random.randint(0, 100))
print(f"Список случайных чисел: {list_numbers}")


А что если в первой половине числа повторяются? А что если количество элементов в списке нечётное?

если числа повторяются, то этот момент решается. а если количество элементов нечётное, то средний элемент должен иметь такое же значение ( например 85:85)

Как именно решается? Что у вас не получается с созданием словаря?

не понимаю как присвоить к первой полине списка в качестве ключей вторую половину в виде значений

Сделайте цикл до len//2, используя индексы i и i+len//2

Используйте zip() для того, чтобы сложить первую и вторую половину.
Пример с учетом того, что числа не повторяются при генерации:
import random

n = int(input("Введите целое число:"))

list_numbers = list()

for num in range(n):
    list_numbers.append(random.randint(0, 100))

print(f"Список случайных чисел: {list_numbers}")

m = n // 2

if n % 2 == 0:
    keys = list_numbers[:m]
    values = list_numbers[m:]
else:
    keys = list_numbers[:m]
    values = list_numbers[m+1:]
    keys.append(list_numbers[m])
    values.append(list_numbers[m])

r = dict(zip(keys, values))
print(r)


большое спасибо!

@Евгений Не забывайте принимать ответы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer
